# Acumatica SQL to BQL - Not In

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I am trying to convert my SQL to BQL but I don't know how to do the NOT IN Statment in BQL. I used NotIn2 with search I am not sure if that is right?
I keep on getting time out issues if I use it so I can't test

```
SELECT INTran.*, 
FROM INTran
     JOIN INTranSplit ON INTran.RefNbr = INTranSplit.RefNbr                             
     JOIN InventoryItem ON InventoryItem.InventoryID = INTran.InventoryID                              
WHERE INTran.LotSerialNbr NOT IN
(
    SELECT LotSerialNbr
    FROM SOShipLineSplit
)
AND InventoryItem.inventoryCD = 'NIS004';
```

I am going to use it in a foreach loop with the below:

```
 foreach (INTran item in PXSelectJoin<
                            INTran,
                            LeftJoin<INTranSplit,
                                On<INTranSplit.refNbr, Equal<INTran.refNbr>>,
                            LeftJoin<InventoryItem,
                                On< INTran.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>,
                            Where<INTran.lotSerialNbr, NotIn2<Search<SOShipLineSplit.lotSerialNbr>>,
                            And<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>
                            >.Select(Base, "NIS004")){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot implement NotIn with subselect that easily in BQL. But here is what you can do:
You can alter the select to get the same result using join:

```
 PXSelectJoin<INTran, 
 InnerJoin<INTranSplit, On<...>, 
 InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<...>, 
 LeftJoin<SOShipLineSplit, On<SOShipLineSplit.lotSerialNbr, Equal<INTran.lotSerialNbr>>>>>,
 Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>,
 And<SOShipLineSplit.ShipmentNbr, IsNull>>
```

In that example you will only select lines for which SOShipLineSplit was not found

Comment: Thanks you  DmitriiI, I keep on getting timeout issues doing this any ideas why?

Comment: I'd recommend you to try the request directly in SQL to see how much time it takes. (You can check the exact SQL request generated using Request Profiler screen). When you execute the request in SQL, check the 'Actual Execution Plan' to see what part of hte request is causing performance issues. It can probably be fixed by adding more conditions to the request or by adding new DB indexes

Comment: Thankx Dmitrii, I will have a look